# BizTalk WCF-Custom" raised an error ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk

I have an interface which is a simple receiveport mapping sendport. The receiveport is the result of an add generated items query. The query just fetches some adres data from the database. This data does contain 'foreign' letters but when i run the query on Oracle SQL Developer, it works fine (gives me 12800 rows).

When BizTalk runs the query, it gives an ORA, which i assumed was an error the db gives to BizTalk am i wrong?

Where do i actually have to fix this problem? and How? Do i need to find out which character set is used on the database and use a convert in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error coming from Oracle - it's very unlikely that it's due to BizTalk or the WCF adapter.  It indicates you have some corrupt data in your Oracle DB.  You may not be getting the error in SQL Developer because SQL Developer is only returning the first ~50 rows by default (until you actually scroll down past them).

I'd use a strategy like this: http://vibhork.blogspot.com/2011/02/fix-of-ora-29275-partial-multibyte.html to try to find the bad data (e.g. page through the rows using `ROWNUM` until you find the row that's in error) - you could simulate that in SQL Developer by just scrolling down until you get the error (I think).  If you can fix the data, fix it - if the data was put there by another source, you'll either have to get that source to stop putting invalid characters in there or you'll have to convert/concat the column(s) that is (are) causing problems, like:

```
 SELECT problem_column || '' FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(COLUMN NAME,'NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_CHARACTERSET') FROM table
```

You might try `SELECT CONVERT(COLUMN NAME, 'UTF8', 'US7ASCII')` for example.

Comment: I have use CTRL + A to fetch all rows, and the data loads without errors in SQL Developer. How would i know what Character sets to use in a CONVERT?

Comment: I'd give it a try with `CONVERT(COLUMN_NAME, 'UTF8', 'US7ASCII')`.  Seems strange that you can load the data correctly in SQL Developer though..  This is definitely an error coming from Oracle, shouldn't be specific to the adapter.  I'd really work to see if I could reproduce it outside the adapter....

Comment: It does work fine in sql developer and the java application that the users use (not an expert myself). Using the CONVERT does fix the problem so i will have to delay the reproducing of the error. Not sure if you want to add the specific COnvert command to your answer or not.

Comment: Glad to hear.  Maybe SQL Developer is automatically doing that conversion or something, not really sure.  Might try systematically removing those from the query until you isolate which column, but hey if it's wokring it's working.